# Reference jQuery plugin options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the inifiteScroll jquery plugin, and I want to reference the options variable from my version of the locading.start function:

```
        var rDealBone = this;
        ($('.deals-list'), this.el).infinitescroll({
            navSelector  : "div.navigation",
            nextSelector : "div.navigation a",
            itemSelector : ".deal",
            debug: true,
            loading: {
                finished: undefined,
                finishedMsg: "<em>Congratulations, you've reached the end of the internet.</em>",
                img: "http://www.infinite-scroll.com/loading.gif",
                msg: null,
                msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>",
                selector: null,
                speed: 'fast',
                start: function(){ 
                    // this is the code from the default start function of the plugin,
                    // the opts refers to the plugin options cariable, how can i refere to it
                    // from this function
                    $(opts.navSelector).hide();
                        opts.loading.msg
                            .appendTo(opts.loading.selector)
                            .show(opts.loading.speed, function () {
                                rDealBone.showMore();
                        });

                }
            },
            pathParse: function(){
                return '/listDeals/offset:' + rDealBone.doffset;
            }
        });
```

How can I reference to the plugin options from inside the start function?

Appreciate the help, Yehia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me as if you can access them through the first param:

```
opts.loading.start.call($(opts.contentSelector)[0],opts);
```

So you'd do:

```
start: function (opts) { console.log(opts);  }
```

I've not used this plugin before so I've not tried this myself.

Comment: thanks a lot, but also what if i want to call the _error function of the infinitescroll, $.infinitescroll._error("end") won't work

Comment: Unfortunately anything prefixed with with an underscore is private so it can't be run through the 'public' interface however whilst I wouldn't recommend it you can run it like this: `$('.deals-list').data('infinitescroll')._error('end');` but it might be worth opening an issue on github and putting a case up for the _error method to be made public if you've got a valid reason to run it.

Comment: Also, if you do want to call a public function (anything that's not prefixed with an underscore) it should be called like this: `$('.deals-list').infinitescroll('methodName', arg1, arg2, etc.);` not directly on `$.infinitescroll` which is actually the constructor function. (which conventionally would be better called `$.Infinitescroll`)

Comment: thanks a lot, i opened an issue on https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/issues/118